# Add column value in table with button click Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a column value number will increase with button click.

Let's say the table is `Cust_Table`, and it has columns `Cust Name` and `Total Contacting`.

I want to add all value with "+1" every time I click the button.

Example:

- Cust A: total contact 1
- Cust B: total contact 2
- Cust C: total contact 5
- Cust D: total contact 3

After I click the button, those values will be increased by 1:

- Cust A: total contact 2
- Cust B: total contact 3
- Cust C: total contact 6
- Cust D: total contact 4

Thanks

Note: Im very new on this, so far i got, and start with how to get range from a table in excel..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim src As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set src = Range("F8").CurrentRegion
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "Cust_Table"

End Sub
```

[image: See this screenshot]

Comment: Here sir, im very new in Macro/VBA.. i start from gather information to get range from the table...

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim src As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set src = Range("F8").CurrentRegion
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "Cust_Table"

End Sub

Comment: Yes sir... now i still looking for reference in google and in this forum but i still cant find..

Like this

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("B1") = Range("B1") + Range("A1")
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a reference to a listobject, you can access the range for a given column heading like this:

```vb
Dim lo as listobject, c as range, v as long

v = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").value 'cell with value to be added
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Cust_Table")
for each c in lo.listcolumns("Total Contacting").DataBodyRange.Cells
    c.value = c.value + v
next c
```

Comment: Thanks mr Tim Williams, youre the best......the code works great...